# How to get notified when ThreadPool is finished?

Tags: c#, threadpool

I have a job-application which does regular imports / exports every X minutes.

Some Imports needs time (e.g. 60 seconds) and to avoid freezing my complete application (I have a log-screen within to see what happens), I implemented Threading to my Worker:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Eigentlicher JobTimer Tick, schmeißt den Worker jeden Tick neu an.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void JobTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WriteLog("Jobtimer Tick");
        JobTimer.Enabled = false;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StartWorker);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// StartWorker Wrapper for Threading
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state"></param>
    private void StartWorker(object state)
    {
        Worker w = new Worker();
        w.StartWork(); //<--- Jobs will be Done here
        JobTimer.Enabled = true; //<---Problem here
    }
```

My Problem is, I have to disable the JobTimer (which ticks every 1000ms to see if there are jobs todo) so the JobTimer doesn't get overruned by jobs that are currently running.
But I can't enable him again, because it seems the JobTimer on the threaded method is not the same as on the call method...

So how can I get notified when my Async ThreadPool is finished?

Comment: The usual way you can notify one thread about what's happening on another thread - use a signalling construct. Of course, that's a waste of time nowadays. Why not use `BackgroundWorker` or `Task` (especially with `await`) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new task-based async/await features make expressing this much easier. How about sacking the timer and restating your problem using tasks:

So:

```
public async Task RunWorkLoop(CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //runs in ThreadPool, doesn't complete until StartWork is done
        await Task.Run(() => new Worker().StartWork()); 
        await Task.Delay(someTimeInterval);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a note that `Task.Delay` uses a timer as well, so it abstracts away pretty much equivallent code. Although I assume the OP used the winforms `Timer` rather than the multi-threaded `Timer`, so there's a difference - you no longer ever marshal back to the UI thread. The OP has to say whether that's needed or not.

Comment: Thanks, can you help me adapt this to my code please?